# RabbitMq: Change x-message-ttl of a queue

Tags: rabbitmq

How can I implement a queue with configurable x-message-ttl?

I have a queue with x-message-ttl set to 1 minute and I want to change it to 2 minute at runtime. How can this be achieved?

I already tried declaring queue again with x-message-ttl = 2 minutes but neither ttl is changing by this nor message is being published.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

if you create a queue with arguments `x-message-ttl` you can't change it, you have to remove and recreate the queue.

but you can use the policies:

1. Create queues **without** ttl arguments
2. create the policy, for example:`rabbitmqctl set_policy expiry ".*" "{""expires"":1800000}" --apply-to queues`

In this way you can change the queue TTL value

Comment: It will change for all QUEUE ... But is it possible to change in particular queue?

Comment: @ShiladittyaChakraborty did you manage how to set for a particular queue?

Comment: @Leonardo I tried 

curl -i -u guest:guest -H "content-type:application/json" -XPUT -d '{"auto_delete":false,"durable":true,"arguments":{"x-message-ttl": 3600000}}' http://localhost:15672/api/queues/vhost/queue_name

received the value '3600000' of type 'long' but current is none.

Looks like it will not work on existing single queue (unable to change arguments)
also noticed if set_policy, then it appears in the policy section of admin console, not on each queue, different from set arguments upon creation of queue.

Comment: For setting a particular policy for just one queue you can set the regex pattern to your queue name (in @Gabriele example it is the regex string `".*"`). So if your queue is named Foo you would just set the regex pattern to be exactly "Foo". See [this doc](https://www.rabbitmq.com/parameters.html) for more help on specifics.

Comment: one important thing to mention. When setting ttl for queue, it won't apply to the messages, that are already landed in queue. It will apply only for new messages added after policy created.